# TCP connection to sumo version 1.14.0 using Java

Tags: java, networking, tcp, simulation, sumo

I've been trying to connect to sumo in windows, using java, with sumo version of 1.14.0. I can establish the connection, but I can't send commands, like simulation step. I have to mention I have codes for older versions of sumo, for the new ones it doesn't work and I'm up to sort of upgrade the older codes. Anybody got any examples how to execute commands using tcp connection in java?

Answer (score 1):

Please do not use TraaS any longer. It is considered deprecated. Use [libsumojni](https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Libsumo.html#java) or [libtracijni](https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Libtraci.html#java) instead:

```
import org.eclipse.sumo.libsumo.Simulation;
import org.eclipse.sumo.libsumo.StringVector;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary("libsumojni");
        Simulation.start(new StringVector(new String[] {"sumo", "-c", "test.sumocfg"}));
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Simulation.step();
        }
        Simulation.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: LibSumo doesn't Provide sumo-gui option in windows. This version that I'm using, is also working with sumo 1.14 and windows sumo-gui.

Comment: But libtraci has GUI support and is far better supported. You can just replace libsumo by libtraci in the example above

Comment: Perfect. I will certainly consider your recommendation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I have figured it out. On sumo protocol documentation there's a link to guid developers how to connect to sumo using three languages. Python, C++ and also java. This [link](https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/blob/main/tools/contributed/traas) is all I needed. You can build connections from scratch or you can exploit the ones that are already implemented, like simulation step. Below there's an example:

```
try {
            CommandProcessor cmdPrc=new CommandProcessor(socket);
            cmdPrc.do_SimulationStep(20.0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

Just create a socket connection and start sumo. And then, using the codes in the link above it is possible to import and run the simulation.

Comment: Again, this is using TraaS, which is deprecated. Please use https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Libtraci.html#java

Comment: The libtraci is not Thread-Safe according to the sumo team. There's no possibility to ask for variables concurrently. But TRAAS is able to provide a thread-safe package. Due to our need to have a thread-safe library we can't use libtraci.